# Manage Paypal IPN with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, paypal-ipn, urlfetch

To manage IPN there is 4 steps  :

1. Receive by post request info of payment by Paypal
2. Return HTTP 200 response
3. Return complete unaltered message to paypal
4. Receive Verified or Invalid from Paypal after 3

To do that there is an example [here](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/ivestartedalittleexperiment#TOC-Annex).
I made some customization of Romain script for my own need but philosophy is the same and I know with Romain we have the same issue with IPN (I'm in contact with him).

The issue is : We can't validate the IPN Process. The HTTP response code is at status 405.

What I have found is in the romain script we do step 3 before step 2. So I made a change and now the script return an empty answer :

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput('');
```

Before sending back the complete unaltered paypal message, I setup a trigger who send message to paypal after 30s :

```
var params = {
    method: "post"
  }
  var req = messge from paypal;
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?"+req,params);
```

This code is not the same as Romain but I well received the "VERIFIED" answer from Paypal.

So now I think issue is the HTTP 200 response send back to paypal, step 2.
What I made is, check the data in content, header and response code by sending my own post request to the apps script. Here the result :

> [15-03-25 22:50:29:753 CET] code : 200
>
> [15-03-25 22:50:29:754 CET] content :
>
> [15-03-25 22:50:29:756 CET] hearder : ({'X-XSS-Protection':"1;
>   mode=block", Expires:"Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT",
>   'Alternate-Protocol':"443:quic,p=0.5",
>   'Set-Cookie':"NID=67=hlLDTKuNN7fjl66UwT9e2_BV0xw_dd67lZ9R337Zm2K8RYNAMzF0FjnEt0uhE0cxCzymgsH-1ehuGOgZ7pHynjWRkM1Y6n0PxXp8RAdyPKgfr-Y4cUrBqoDZdUib9zWo;Domain=.googleusercontent.com;Path=/;Expires=Thu,
>   24-Sep-2015 21:50:29 GMT;HttpOnly", Server:"GSE",
>   'Cache-Control':"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
>   Pragma:"no-cache", 'X-Content-Type-Options':"nosniff",
>   'X-Frame-Options':"SAMEORIGIN", 'Transfer-Encoding':"chunked",
>   Date:"Wed, 25 Mar 2015 21:50:29 GMT",
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':"*", P3P:"CP=\"This is not a P3P policy!
>   See
>   http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657
>   for more info.\"", 'Content-Type':"text/plain; charset=utf-8"})

I have found this message on stackoverflow about http response status 405 and a test to do : ([IPN delivery failed. HTTP error code 405: Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162022/ipn-delivery-failed-http-error-code-405-method-not-allowed)).

The header send back with appscript after a dopost() request does not seems to be well formated. I'm not sure about that but now I don't have other idea.

If someone have an idea ?
I thought may be send a custom answer with specific header at the end of the `doPost()` with apps script but don't know how to do that ?

Comment: In step2 is it expecting to get the content as ContentService.MimeType.TEXT ?

Comment: Not necessary. In romain script content is defined adn in mine not but result is the same.

Comment: I still investigate and I have tested with www.hurl.it to send a request to a published script. On the interface I can activate or not follow redirect. If I activate hurl receive a 200 ok response code if not hurl receive 302 Moved Temporarily. I think it that the issue paypal ipn does not follow redirect and don't see the 200 reponse code ???? I don't know if we can check if it that the issue ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

After Kristoffer comment if you use the createHtmlOutputFromFile() it will return a page without redirect and in this Paypal will get a 200 ok code.
So in your script you can return :

```
HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

where test is an HTML file without content.

***Previous answer***

Finally I found a solution. The issue seems really to be because Paypal IPN does not follow redirect.
The test made on hurl.it show that when you don't follow redirect, POST request to an appsscript return a 302 Moved Temporary and a 200 if you follow redirect.

To solve this issue my idea has been to create a simple script that will forward the post request to my apps script but return a 200 ok response to paypal.

I made this script with PHP because I can host it easily and I'm not a huge developper I imagine it is possible to do that on app engine without overpass the free plan.

So if you have a blog here the code I use.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/ID_OF_THE_SCRIPT/exec';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

This work fine now on my Paypal console, I have a 200 response code with status sent and my script work as I received a VERFIFIED from PayPal when I sent back the message.

If the code can be improved I'm interested but for now it is doing the job as I want.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to use the [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/), not ContentService, to return. As noted in the comments, it is the redirect that creates the error - there is an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2707) filed for this. HtmlService does not have this issue, and since all Paypal IPN needs is a HTTP 200, what you return doesn't really matter.

**SOLUTION:**
Change

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput('');
```

to

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

Comment: Thank you but I already try and test it again but it will not work as the issue is the redirect. In fact what we need is google does not redirect and return rigth after Paypal send ipn a 200 ok code.

Comment: There is no redirect when you use HtmlService. I currently use GAS to handle Paypal IPN, causing no errors. Make sure that you test the _Current Web App URL_ ( that ends with /exec ). Using the _latest code_ one (that ends with /dev) will give a 302..

Comment: I'm a bit surprised because we are 2 facing the same issue. We receive IPN it is not the issue the issue is PayPal does not receive 200 OK code. Do you check your IPN history and validate all your IPN are at status sent? I have tested all possible Dev exec return htmloutput return contenttext etc...

Comment: I was getting 405's on my IPN's, then switched to HtmlService and that seemed to solve the issue - now I'm getting HTTP 200s. I'm actually returning using _createHtmlOutputFromFile('randomfile')_ to return some random content (a div with some text). Also, I'm doing step 3 before number 2 - Paypal doesn't seem to mind.

Comment: And - from [Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#other_notify_mechanisms) : _PayPal expects to receive a response to an IPN message within 30 seconds. Consequently, your listener must not perform time-consuming operations (such as updating a database) before responding to an IPN._

Comment: And, sorry for the spam. You should also change your verification URL from ´https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?´ to ´https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate&´

Comment: Ok I have tested and when you return an html output file it does not have redirect and in this case we don't need a post forward. It is really tricky as with contentservice there is a redirect and not with file output. Tested on hurl.it and no redirect. Thank you I will update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I've been having a similar issue which also ended in a 302 redirect. If you encounter this type of problem make sure:

a) You follow both Kristoffer and St3ph instructions. They do work.

b) (my issue) **When deploying** the web app, **choose to run the app as "me"**, not as "User accessing the web app", as shown in the image.

Failing to do so you will get a 302 redirect for authentication reasons.
[image]

Comment: Execute the app as "me" - doesn't work(at least now).